# Online REST open api, which accepts only String as RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I want a online REST open API (POST Method), which accepts RequestBody as String only.
I have to ping a message to that open API.

```
 restTemplate.postForEntity("myRequestUrl", "my message", String.class);
```

Comment: Hello. It's unclear what you are asking/trying to do. Can you add examples? Are you trying to write the client or the server for this API (or both)? What is not working with your current solution?

Comment: @knittl I have to call it using restTemplate client.

Comment: please let us know what is not working. I can send the string and receive the (string) response just fine: `System.out.println(restTemplate.postForObject("https://webhook.site/2ab3af1a-04ed-44b8-bc65-d0ce27d0b297", "myping", String.class));`

Comment: Maybe the confusion stems from `postForEntity` vs `postForObject`?

Comment: @knittl let me try this, I think this url will work. I was looking for open url which will take string as body.

Comment: @knittl can you write the answer, I will accept if it works. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234716/discussion-between-shiva-and-knittl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several websites which offer public APIs to test requests, including, but not limited to:

- https://httpbin.org / http://httpbin.org/
- https://webhook.site
- https://test-api.k6.io
- https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
- https://reqres.in
- https://fakestoreapi.com

---

You can also find a list of public APIs at https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis. Those are not necessarily test APIs, but they return real data. Maybe it is useful to somebody.